# Back button redirects to login page

Tags: jsp, jstl

Developing a code in JSP.

After login, I am setting sessions and to prevent the "back button" from redirecting back to login page I used this in the login page:

```
<c:if test="${not empty user}">
<c:redirect url="home.jsp"></c:redirect></c:if>
```

user is the session object that is being set. The code doesn't work. Please advice.

Comment: Show how you're setting an user in the session.

Comment: if the user is set on the page, rather than the session then this may happen.